# Word VBA: Run-time error 5453.Word has finished searching the document

Tags: vba, ms-word, runtime-error

I am working on a VBA Macro in Word and among other things I am calling the EditFind Dialog Window.

If Word has searched the document more than once and finds what I am searching for, after closing the Dialog Window, I get the error message "Run-time error 5453. Word has finished searching the document".

Is it possible to make it disappear? It is confusing to the people who are going to use it because in the end it finds what it is looking for but stops my macro.

```
With Dialogs(wdDialogEditFind)
 .MatchCase = False
 .Show
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh found it already myself.

Since it's not really a big deal of an error I use

`On Error Resume Next`

that just ignores the error and moves to the next activity.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is not the solution to your problem - from experience this will come back to bite you some time in the future. You should try and track down the exact issue causing the error.

Comment: That's what I also thought but I didn't find a better solution. The error is caused by the Find option. If I loop through the file more than once and find my answer and close the Find window, I get the message.